# NPM / NodeJS command prompt errors

Tags: node.js, shell, visual-studio-code, npm, command-prompt

I have been trying to look for answers all over and I cannot find any.. Whenever I go to create a react app, (I use visual studio code) I will type in the terminal (I do the NPX lowercase but stack overflow wouldn't let me post if lowercase) `NPX create-react-app title` and it will open up a new command prompt for a split second then just close.. all i get to see is an error called `NPM WARN` then it closes.. This happens for almost all NPM commands I do.. Is there any way I can fix this, it is really starting to get annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the cause of the error is not clear, first try

`npm init react-app my-app`

command be sure using npm version 6 or higher. If it doesn't work try

`npm install -g create-react-app`

then use

`npx create-react-app hello-world`

command again.

If none of this commands work, you can uninstall npm and other libraries, frameworks related to react then install the last stable versions of them.